# How to display comments in a Post. with Node, express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

my `showpost.ejs`
this file displays a single post with comments of that post. `onepost` is a single post `variable` that contains a `post`

```
<% if(onepost) { %>

  <form action="/post/<%=onepost.id%>/comment" method="POST">
     <textarea name="content"
        rows="10" cols="50">Write something here
     </textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Post comment">
     </form>
<% } %>

<% onepost.comments.forEach(com => { %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= com.content %></li>
    </ul>
<% });%>
```

and this is my index.js file

```
router.post("/post/:id/comment", async (req, res) => {
     // Find post
   const post = await Post.findOne({_id: req.params.id});

    // create a comment
  const comment = new Comment();
  comment.content = req.body.content;
  comment.post = post._id;
  await comment.save();

    // Associating post with comments

  post.comments.push(comment._id);
  await post.save();
  res.send(comment);

});
```

I want the `comments` to display under each `post` so that when you click on the `post` it will display that `comments` that was created and associated to it.
The `comment` is getting created without any problem,and it displays on the console, my problem now is that it doesn't display on the browser.
My background is `Ruby` on `Rails` but i just started learning `Node` and `express` recently by myself by following examples on YouTube and stack-overflow.
Please, i need a help on how to display the `comments` in the `View`, i don't know the right way to call the comments from the post that they are attached to.

Comment: Are you asking how to query your comments based on the post or are you asking how to display comments in the UI via ejs?

Comment: i am asking how to display comment in the UI via ejs.

Comment: why don't use share your schema?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing `res.send` you need to do it like this:

```
res.render('showpost', {
  comment 
});
```

I am assuming that you have the `showpost.ejs` file in your `views` folder. And now to render this comment you can do the following in `showpost.ejs`:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= comment.content %></li>
</ul>
```

If you are passing array of comments then you can loop throw and display them. Here i showed you how you can do a single comment that you are saving. Hope this will help you.

Comment: i tried the example you gave but it threw an error that the `comment` is not defined **comment is not defined**

Comment: The problem is that `comment` is not available inside `showpost.ejs`

Comment: Is your file located in `project_root/views/postshow.ejs`?

Comment: Yes that's where it's located.

Comment: Please,  is there anyone that can still help me here.

Comment: why don't you share your schema? what is the endpoint for getting your posts.?          you need sth like this: Blog.find().populate('comments') with its associated comments, I assume comments is a field in Blog schema